# Как привязять свойство интерфейса в ячейку DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Класс `OrderItem` реализует интерфейс `ItemInterface`

В интерфейсе `ItemInterface` определено свойство `ItemName` (string) которое реализовано в классе

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Project.Data
{
    public class OrderItem : ItemInterface
    {
        public Item item { get; set; }
        public Decimal price { get; set; }
        public int amount { get; set; }


        string ItemInterface.ItemName { get { return item.name; } }

    }
}
```

Как привязать значение ItemName к ячейке, в которой должно отображаться это название?

```
<DataGrid x:Name="OrderItemGrid" 
  IsReadOnly="True"
  Focusable="False"
  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Название" Binding="{Binding Path=ItemName)}"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

Сейчас в лог падает сообщение об ошибке и в ячейке пусто

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ItemName' property not found on 'object' ''OrderItem' (HashCode=66476022)'. BindingExpression:Path=ItemName; DataItem='OrderItem' (HashCode=66476022); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Реализуйте интерфейс `ItemInterface` неявно. К явно реализованным членам доступ возможен только по интерфейсной ссылке, в вашем случае - `ItemInterface`.

```
public class OrderItem : ItemInterface
{
    public Item item { get; set; }
    public Decimal price { get; set; }
    public int amount { get; set; }

    public string ItemName { get { return item.name; } }
}
```

Кроме того, т.к. свойство `ItemName` имеет только метод доступа `get` в привязке необходимо явно включить режим `Mode=OneWay`.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Название" Binding="{Binding Path=ItemName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Именно эти две причины не давали вам выполнить привязку к свойству `ItemName`.